# HandlebarsJS - JSON with special characters

Tags: json, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have a JSON-file which contains special characters and I want to display the JSON with `HandlebarsJS` but I cant get it to work:

the JSON structure is this:

```
{
  "feed" : {
      "entry" : {
          "title": {
              "$t" : "THIS TITLE I WANT"
           }
       }
}
```

I use `BackboneJS`, so inside my Collection I do:

```
parse: function(data) {
    return data.feed.entry    
}
```

So I tried to do

```
{{#each this}}

 <p>{{title.$t}}</p>

{{/each}}
```

But it doesnt work!?!?!

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: What do you pass to handlebars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there but Handlebars handles loops over properties differently.
Basically what's happening is that there's an implicit conversion of `this` in an each loop when dealing with objects.

```
{{#each this}}
   //Here we think that **this** refers to an entry, but's it's not.
   //Cue implicit context switch to point **this** to the title object.
   //"unpack" it, and use the keys you're after.
   <p>{{$t}}</p> //voilà, we get the value.
{{/each}}
```

A very simple example is this ([JsBin here](http://jsbin.com/lewirehu/2/edit)):

```
<script id="cool" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each this}}
      <p>{{socool}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</script>
var cool = {cool: {'socool': "brrr!!!" }};
var compiled = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById("cool").innerHTML);

console.log(compiled(cool));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the suggestion from the user, who now has deleted his answer was right!!

```
{{#each this}}

    <p>{{title.[$t]}}</p>

{{/each}}
```

Makes it work! So if you read this, post your answer again and I will accept it!!

Comment: You can access it like a normal property `title.$t` too.